# DataTable writeToXML not writing unchecked box

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview, dataset

I am saving my datatable to an XML file:

Here is what the values are when all boxes are checked:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <Startup_x0020_App_x0020_Table>
    <Program_x0020_Location>5</Program_x0020_Location>
    <Name>5</Name>
    <Delay>true</Delay>
    <StartOnStartup>true</StartOnStartup>
    <KeepAlive>true</KeepAlive>
  </Startup_x0020_App_x0020_Table>
</DocumentElement>
```

Here are the values when only two of the boxes are checked before being saved:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <Startup_x0020_App_x0020_Table>
    <Program_x0020_Location>7</Program_x0020_Location>
    <Name>7</Name>
    <Delay>true</Delay>
    <KeepAlive>true</KeepAlive>
  </Startup_x0020_App_x0020_Table>
</DocumentElement>
```

My question is when using :

```
 _dataTable.WriteXml(_xmlLocation);
```

How to write even unchecked boxes?

Because when I load this xml file using:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(xml);
MyDataGridView.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
```

It only shows the checkbox columns that have been checked ( if I only saved one row for example )

Thanks!

Comment: Take an overload of WriteXml that taken an XmlWriteMode Parameter also and specify that the Schema should be written.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you mean, could you provide a brief example perhaps? Thanks!

Comment: The columns amount for the loaded dataset is 4, when it should be 5. When saving it does not save the unchecked columns if at least one is not checked

Answer (score 0):

You want to see all columns defined in the DataTable, so you need to store the schema of that DataTable in the xml to have the complete table/column definitions.

```
_dataTable.TableName = "MyLovelyTableName"; // you must have a TableName
_dataTable.WriteXml(_xmlLocation, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

It won't help if you could (you can't by the way) store the defaults of a cell also. You still won't have type information. How should ReadXml distinguish between null and an empty string? How should the boolean value true be distinguished from a string true? Should the name column be identified as a number or a string? Name doesn't sound like a number. Either way you need type information to do the right thing and you shouldn't rely on type guessing.

Comment: Ralf : WriteXML using DataTable doesn't work.. Yoou need to add DataTable to a DataSet and then use WriteXML on DataSet.

Comment: As long as the dataTable has a name (TableName property set) it works. I will add that info.